Why can't my Box3 bounding box detect an intersect between my GLTF/FBX models?
I'm new to ThreeJS so I don't know if the Box3 is commonly used for collision detection.
I've attached a Box3 bounding box to detect collision and prevent the character from walking into the bounding box of the building. When I drew out a helper line, I can clearly see that the bounding boxes are there. But when my character walks into the building and the two bounding boxes intersect, it doesn't seem to console log out the intersects.
The character bounding box can move with the character because I added it to the container instead of directly adding it to the scene. I'm not sure if this is the correct way (are there such things are layers in ThreeJS where container is a different layer from scene?)
const buildingboundingBox = new THREE.Box3()


fbxLoader.load( //FBX model for the building 
    one_story.href,
    (object) => {
        object.scale.set(0.25, 0.25, 0.25)
        object.position.set(60, 0, 0)
        object.rotateY(-0.5 * Math.PI)
        scene.add(object)
        buildingboundingBox.setFromObject(object);
        const buildingBBhelper = new THREE.Box3Helper(buildingboundingBox, 0x00ff00);
        scene.add(buildingBBhelper);
    }, (error) => { console.log(error) }
);

//#region CHARACTERS
//All logics for the character
const raycaster = new THREE.Raycaster();
raycaster.far = 100;
const characterboundingBox = new THREE.Box3()
gltf.load(character3.href, function (gltf) {
    model = gltf.scene;

    model.position.set(0, 0, 0)
    model.scale.set(10, 10, 10)
    container.add(model);

    mixer = new THREE.AnimationMixer(model);
    const clips = gltf.animations;

    const idleClip = THREE.AnimationClip.findByName(clips, 'Idle');
    const idleAction = mixer.clipAction(idleClip);

    const idleShootClip = THREE.AnimationClip.findByName(clips, 'Idle_Gun');
    const idleShootAction = mixer.clipAction(idleShootClip);

    const walkClip = THREE.AnimationClip.findByName(clips, 'Run');
    const walkAction = mixer.clipAction(walkClip);

    const walkShootClip = THREE.AnimationClip.findByName(clips, 'Run_Gun');
    const walkShootAction = mixer.clipAction(walkShootClip);

    idleAction.play();
    walkShootAction.stop();
    walkAction.stop();
    idleShootAction.stop();

    let newPosition = container.position.clone().add(new THREE.Vector3(0, 5, 0));

    function updateNewPosition() {
        newPosition = container.position.clone().add(new THREE.Vector3(0, 5, 0));
    }

    //setting the bounding box for the character
    characterboundingBox.setFromObject(model);
    const helper = new THREE.Box3Helper(characterboundingBox, 0xff0000);
    container.add(helper);

    // Key and mouse events
    window.addEventListener("keydown", (e) => {
        const { keyCode } = e;
        if ((keyCode === 87 || keyCode === 38) && isPlaying) {
            // baseActions.idle.weight = 0;
            // baseActions.run.weight = 5;
            // activateAction(baseActions.run.action);
            // activateAction(baseActions.idle.action);
            idleAction.stop();
            if (mousedown) { walkShootAction.play(); }
            else { walkAction.play(); }
            movingForward = true;
        }
        if (keyCode == 27 && isPlaying) {
            isPlaying = false;
            body.style.cursor = 'default';

        }
        if (keyCode == 32 && !isPlaying) {
            isPlaying = true;

            body.style.cursor = 'none';

        }
        if (characterboundingBox.intersectsBox(buildingboundingBox)) {
            console.log("collided");
        }
    });
    window.addEventListener("keyup", (e) => {
        const { keyCode } = e;
        if (keyCode === 87 || keyCode === 38) {
            // baseActions.idle.weight = 1;
            // baseActions.run.weight = 0;
            // activateAction(baseActions.run.action);
            // activateAction(baseActions.idle.action);
            walkAction.stop();
            walkShootAction.stop();
            movingForward = false;
        }
    });
    window.addEventListener("pointerdown", (e) => {
        if (!isPlaying) return;

        if (movingForward == true) {
            idleAction.stop();
            walkAction.stop();
            idleShootAction.stop();
            walkShootAction.play();
        } else {
            idleAction.stop();
            walkAction.stop();
            walkShootAction.stop();
            idleShootAction.play();
        }

        // pointer.x = (e.clientX / window.innerWidth) * 2 - 1;
        // pointer.y = - (e.clientY / window.innerHeight) * 2 + 1;
        // pointer.x = 0;
        // pointer.y = 0;
        // raycaster.setFromCamera(pointer, camera);
        updateNewPosition();

        let forward = new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 1);
        forward.applyQuaternion(model.quaternion);

        raycaster.set(newPosition, forward);

        const intersects = raycaster.intersectObjects(scene.children);
        for (let i = 0; i < intersects.length; i++) {
            // console.log(intersects[i].object.name);
            if (intersects[i].object.name == "Zombie_Arm") {
                console.log("hit");
                zombie1Health = 0;
            }
            if (intersects[i].object.name == "Zombie") {
                console.log("hit");
                zombie2Health = 0;
            }
            if (intersects[i].object.name == "Zombie_Chubby") {
                console.log("hit");
                zombie3Health = 0;
            }
        }

        // scene.add(new THREE.ArrowHelper(raycaster.ray.direction, raycaster.ray.origin, 300, 0xff0000));

        mousedown = true;
    });
    window.addEventListener("pointerup", (e) => {
        if (movingForward == true) {
            walkShootAction.stop();
            walkAction.play();
        } else {
            idleShootAction.stop();
            idleAction.play();
        }
        mousedown = false;
    });
    window.addEventListener("pointermove", (e) => {
        if (isPlaying) {
            const { movementX, movementY } = e;
            const offset = new THREE.Spherical().setFromVector3(
                camera.position.clone().sub(cameraOrigin)
            );
            const phi = offset.phi - movementY * 0.02;
            offset.theta -= movementX * 0.02;
            offset.phi = Math.max(0.01, Math.min(0.35 * Math.PI, phi));
            camera.position.copy(
                cameraOrigin.clone().add(new THREE.Vector3().setFromSpherical(offset))
            );
            camera.lookAt(container.position.clone().add(cameraOrigin));
        }
    });



});
//#endregion

function animate() {
    // requestAnimationFrame(animate);
    var delta = clock.getDelta();


    // Check for collisions
    if (characterboundingBox.intersectsBox(buildingboundingBox)) {
        console.log("Collided with building!");
    }

    updateZombie1Animation();
    updateZombie2Animation();
    updateZombie3Animation();

    if (mixer) mixer.update(delta);
    if (zombMixer) zombMixer.update(delta);
    if (zombMixer1) zombMixer1.update(delta);
    if (zombMixer2) zombMixer2.update(delta);

    if (movingForward) {
        // Get the X-Z plane in which camera is looking to move the player
        camera.getWorldDirection(tempCameraVector);
        const cameraDirection = tempCameraVector.setY(0).normalize();

        // Get the X-Z plane in which player is looking to compare with camera
        model.getWorldDirection(tempModelVector);
        const playerDirection = tempModelVector.setY(0).normalize();

        // Get the angle to x-axis. z component is used to compare if the angle is clockwise or anticlockwise since angleTo returns a positive value
        const cameraAngle = cameraDirection.angleTo(xAxis) * (cameraDirection.z > 0 ? 1 : -1);
        const playerAngle = playerDirection.angleTo(xAxis) * (playerDirection.z > 0 ? 1 : -1);

        // Get the angle to rotate the player to face the camera. Clockwise positive
        const angleToRotate = playerAngle - cameraAngle;

        // Get the shortest angle from clockwise angle to ensure the player always rotates the shortest angle
        let sanitisedAngle = angleToRotate;
        if (angleToRotate > Math.PI) {
            sanitisedAngle = angleToRotate - 2 * Math.PI
        }
        if (angleToRotate < -Math.PI) {
            sanitisedAngle = angleToRotate + 2 * Math.PI
        }

        // Rotate the model by a tiny value towards the camera direction
        model.rotateY(
            Math.max(-0.05, Math.min(sanitisedAngle, 0.05))
        );
        container.position.add(cameraDirection.multiplyScalar(0.05));
        camera.lookAt(container.position.clone().add(cameraOrigin));
    }

    renderer.render(scene, camera)
}
renderer.setAnimationLoop(animate);

